# Kubernetes, how to work with multiple Instance of the same Service?

Tags: kubernetes, coredns

I'm pretty new to K8. I wonder, what is the best practices for working with CoreDNS and multiple Instances of the same Service. Does it make Sense to register a Load Balancer to CoreDNS, which then handles the distribution of requests? Or is the default random ordering of the Response from CoreDNS enough?

Sorry if im asking a stupid question, I just haven't found anything in the Docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kubernetes has a [service resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) that points to a set of pods and directs traffic to them

The service can be either internal (ClusterIP) or have external interface (NodePort / LoadBalancer) according to your needs